# printing all running session variable in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5.1

How do I print all running session variable in Laravel 5.1?

I want to print all the running session variable. Currently I can retrieve single running session for given value but don't know the function for print all at one time with one function something like

```
{{ Session::get(all)}}
```

Comment: Do you want all active sessions, or all variables in the current session?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you just want to see contents of session, try `dd()`:

```
dd(session()->all());
```

If not, just use this to get all info:

```
$data = session()->all();
```

More on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage).

Comment: print_r(session()->all()) ; works for me, Thanks Alexey.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `dd(Session::all());`

Comment: Why dont people use this syntax. Why's everybody (laraval doc too) sticking to simple query?

Comment: coz helpers are simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can display sessions contents as :

```
$sessions=session()->all();
```

or

```
$sessions=Session::all();
```

to print contents use :

```
foreach($sessions as $k=>$v){
    echo $k."=".$v." ";
}
//or use : 
dd(session()->all()) ; // this is  var_dump equeivelent
```

to use specific session key :

```
$user_id = session('user_id'); // key : user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see all session by using session's **all()** method.

```
return session()->all(); // returns all session
return session()->get('name_of_session'); // returns specific session
```

Comment: both are not working in `AuthServiceProvider.php` file. Thanks.